# Regex for internal URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches with internal URLs (the ones that don't include the domain or http) that I can find in a file like this one:

> category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1

For that I'm using:

```
/\w+\/.+\/[\w\-]+/
```

But some URLs are like this:

> category/subcategory

And I need a regular expression that also catch those. Do I have to create a different one or is it possible to create one that match both examples? Is for a BASH script but if you have an idea it does not matter if it is for other engine.

Thank you!!

Update: I forgot the context. Each line of the file is like this:

> "11","category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/item-1","index.php?option=com_trombinoscopeextended&Itemid=125&lang=es&view=trombinoscope","251","0","0000-00-00","","","","","","","0"

Or like this:

> "4","category/subcategory","index.php?option=com_trombinoscopeextended&Itemid=121&lang=es","0","1","0000-00-00","","","","","","","0"

I need to extract the examples for each line.

Thanks.

Comment: Try [`\w+(\/[\w-]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/K0lqCr/2)

Comment: You probably need to describe what else is in that file that you DON'T want to match.  Particularly anything that has `/` in it, since that's the only thing we've got to go on in that last URL.  And are the URLs on their own lines, or have or don't have specific text around them?  Otherwise `5 = 10/2` creates the URL `10/2`

Comment: `^(?:[^/]*/)*[^/]+/?$` might work.

Comment: @zzxyz Yes sorry. I updated with the information about context.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Yes it worked perfectly. How do we proceed to mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\w+(\/[\w-]+)+/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0lqCr/2).

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(\/[\w-]+)+` - 1 or more consecutive sequences of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[\w-]+` - 1+ word or `-` chars.

A hint: you might read in your string with a kind of a CSV parser using your preferred language, and then only return fields that match `^\w+(\/[\w-]+)+$` pattern (here, `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty specific.  I came up with this one after some testing.  We have subdomains we need to check for as well.

```
(?!https?:)/?[^/][^/].*|(https?:)?//([^.]*\.)?yourdomain\.com(/.*)?
```

Someone can probably make it better, but this works for me.